# Phone bricks when I uninstall package installer - can I block app install?

Tags: adb, installation, uninstallation, system-apps

I have a phone that I am trying to block from being able to install apps. I tried removing package installer via ADB, but when I did that the phone bricked upon being restarted, and had to be hard reset. My question is a) is there a way to avoid the phone bricking when package installer is removed, and b) is there a way to totally and permanently block app install without removing package installer? Thanks!

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of the question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/182814/96277). Would you mention the real purpose of preventing installation of any app via any route? It does not seem like a good strategy on its own. No app would be updated. Internet facing obsolete app versions exposes an Android device to malware infection (think of Pegasus malware), on top of the exposure it already has by not receiving OS level security updates.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm searching for the same: to block app installations on a child's device (Cubot KKM2 with Android 10). I also tried disabling the Package Installer (via SDMaid) and the phone failed to start normally next time, so for modern Androids probably another solution is needed. I also tried [AppLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sp.protector.free) (a free app from Google Play), but it couldn't maintain the protection - the child managed to bypass it :)

Comment: @antonK not yet. What does your kid need on there, though? Maybe you could get a specialty device or internet filter on it.

Comment: @Firelord I don't want a browser/any other apps on my phone, and I don't want to be able to install any, in any way. Its for religious reasons.

Comment: @Antonk Or use an ipad, where you can block app store, and there are no apk-type-installs.